# Force WhenEvent and NDSolve to numerical evaluation and Best Practice

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, programming, evaluation

I'm trying to perform an hybrid kalman filter for a nonlinear system.
The following code works but it is very slow due to the fact that it does symbolic evaluation.
What I wish is that for the filter equations first of all it does numeric substitution for the time dependent function and only then do all the actions specified by the algorithm step.
This is the code, **only the last part** is what really interests me.

```
(*SOME FUNCTIONS I'VE USED*)

CreateWhiteNoise[\[Mu]_, s_, t0_, tfin_, dt_, p_] := Module[{distr, n = Length[\[Mu]], listt, nc, listrn},
    listt = Range[t0, tfin, dt];
    nc = Length[listt];
    distr = MultinormalDistribution[\[Mu], s];
    listrn = RandomVariate[distr, nc];
    (Interpolation[Thread[Join[{listt, listrn[[All, #]]}]]][p])&/@Range@n
]


ListForm[mat_] := DeleteCases[(Thread@#&/@Thread@mat//Flatten ), True]

SymRed[mat_] := Module[{i, j, temp},
    temp = Thread@#&/@Thread@mat;
     Normal@SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i >= j :> temp[[i, j]], {i_, j_} /; i < j :> True}, Dimensions@temp]//ListForm
]


(*SYSTEM PART*)
t0 = 0;
tfin = 4 Pi;
pstl = {xstl, ystl};
R0l[\[Theta]_] = {{Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]]} , {Sin[\[Theta]], 
    Cos[\[Theta]]}};
pmk1 = {xmk1, ymk1};
pmk2 = {xmk2, ymk2};
numericalvalues = 
  Thread[{l1, l2, xstl, ystl, xmk1, ymk1, xmk2, ymk2} -> {8, 5, 
     3, -2, 32, 16, -15, 2}];


qalist = {x, y, \[Theta], xstls, ystls};
qa[t_] = (ToString[#] <> "[t]") & /@ qalist // ToExpression;
qad[t_] = D[qa[t], t];
qadd[t_] = D[qa[t], t];

v[t_] = 2;
\[Omega][t_] = 1;
input[t_] = {v[t], \[Omega][t]};

g1 = {Cos[#], Sin[#], 0, 0, 0} & @(#[[3]]) &;
g2 = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
dyn = (g1@#*v[t] + g2*\[Omega][t]) &;


pstf = ({#1, #2} + R0l[#3 ].{#4, #5}) &;
h1 = (Sqrt[#.#] &[pmk1 - pstf @@ #]) &;
h2 = (Sqrt[#.#] &[pmk2 - pstf @@ # ]) &;



CreateWhiteNoise[\[Mu]_, s_, t0_, tfin_, dt_, p_] := 
 Module[{distr, n = Length[\[Mu]], listt, nc, listrn},
    listt = Range[t0, tfin, dt];
    nc = Length[listt];
    distr = MultinormalDistribution[\[Mu], s];
    listrn = RandomVariate[distr, nc];
    (Interpolation[Thread[Join[{listt, listrn[[All, #]]}]]][p]) & /@ 
   Range@n
  ] (*Just create white noise continuous time sample*)


cov = {{0.008, 0}, {0, 
   0.008}}; (*(0.008//Sqrt) *3 \[Equal] 0.268 [m]*)
media = {0, 0};
noise = CreateWhiteNoise[media, cov, t0, tfin + 0.1, 0.04, t ];


h = {h1@#, h2@#} & ;
hn = (h@# + noise) &;
output[t_] = Join[h@qa[t], hn@qa[t]] /. numericalvalues;


eqdyn = qad[t] == dyn@qa[t];

qa0 = Flatten@{-2, 1, Pi/3, pstl} /. numericalvalues;
eqin = qa[0] == qa0;

monitor = {qa[t], input[t], output[t]};

{state, in, out} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqdyn, eqin}, monitor, {t, t0, tfin}];

(*ParametricPlot[state[[1 ;; 2]], {t, t0, tfin}] -> circumference *)



(*FILTER PART*)
qlisthat = (ToString@# <> "hat" // ToExpression) & /@ qalist ;
qahat[t_] = (ToString@# <> "[t]" // ToExpression) & /@ qlisthat;
qahatd[t_] = D[qahat[t], t];
nstate = Length@qlisthat;
Pmat = Normal@
   SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i >= j :> 
      ToExpression["p" <> ToString@i <> ToString@j],
                        {i_, j_} /; i < j :> 
      ToExpression["p" <> ToString@j <> ToString@i ]}, 
    nstate*{1, 1}];
P[t_] = Array[ToExpression[(ToString@Pmat[[#1, #2]] <> "[t]")] &, 
   Dimensions[Pmat]];
Pd[t_] = D[P[t], t];
P0 = IdentityMatrix[nstate]*{0.005, 0.005, 0.3 Degree, 0.005, 
    0.005 };
stima0 = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[ qa0, P0]];
initstima = qahat[0] == stima0;
initcov = P[0] == P0 // SymRed;

predoutput = h@qahat[t] /. numericalvalues;
errstima = {xstls[t] - xstlshat[t], ystls[t] - ystlshat[t]};
A = D[dyn@qa[t], {qa[t]}] /. Thread[ qa[t] -> qahat[t]];
Ci = D[h@qa[t], {qa[t]}] /. Thread[qa[t] -> qahat[t]] /. 
   numericalvalues;
K = P[t].Ci\[Transpose].Inverse[cov];
errpred = hn@qa[t] - predoutput /. numericalvalues;

initEKF = {initstima, initcov};

monitorEKF = {qa[t], qahat[t], errstima};

(* INTERESTING PART - HYBRID KALMAN FILTER*)

dt = 0.1;

Sk = Ci.P[t].Ci\[Transpose] + cov;
Lk = P[t].Ci\[Transpose].Inverse[Sk];
updateP = (IdentityMatrix[nstate] - Lk.Ci).P[t].Transpose[
     IdentityMatrix[nstate] - Lk.Ci] + Lk.cov.Lk\[Transpose];
updateStima = qahat[t] + Lk.errpred;

eqCorr = WhenEvent[Mod[t, dt], 
   Evaluate@{qahat[t] -> updateStima, 
     P[t] -> updateP // SymRed, {"RestartIntegration"}}];

 eqPredStima = qahatd[t] == dyn@qahat[t];
eqPredCov =  Pd[t] == A.P[t] + P[t].A\[Transpose] // SymRed ;
eqEkfIbrid = {eqPredStima, eqPredCov, eqCorr};

{statoEkfIbrid, stimaEkfIbrid, errstimaEkfIbrid} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqdyn, eqin, eqEkfIbrid, initEKF}, 
   monitorEKF, {t, t0, 2}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

Plot[errstimaEkfIbrid, {t, t0, 2}]
```

[image]

At the moment the code is terribly slow, I'm sure it can be improved by forcing in some way numerical evaluation.
An other question: What is the best best practice do formulate an algorithm as this one and more in general to make NDSolve give the best performances ? Do you think is better to explicit every time the arguments of each quantity so that we can use the _?NumericQ pattern test to force numerical evaluation ? I've also seen used for example NDSolve inside Block sometimes, does it help ?

Comment: It is not working code, some functions like  `eqns` and `altEKF` not defined.

Comment: @AlexTrounev damn i'm gonna fix them. It should go now, thanks for having said

Comment: One step `dt` takes about 0.003 s on my laptop, but   20 steps take 93.4 s with your code. It means, that code nothing do during 93.4-20*0.003=93.34 s, and time can be reduced to 0.1 s. For this we can organize `Module` for one step computation and then use this module without  `WhenEvent`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'm sorry for my less knowledge about the software, without WhenEvent how can I say to update the initial conditions every dt seconds ?

Comment: Actually `Module` has initial state and final state. While for `WhenEvent` we need to prepare some rule in general form and it takes 93.34 s with 20 steps, for `Module` we need to prepare numerical data for the next step, and it takes 0.1 s.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I don't know if I've understood correctly the implementation, I should use Module to solve the differential equations from t to t+dt and successively update the results repeating the procedure 20 times ? In this case to track the evolution of the differential variables do you think the best tool is to use Piecewise to join together all the solutions framments ?

Comment: Actually we can make `Do` loop and collect all data from every step. May be I have a chance to make code for you, but your code so complicated for implementation. Therefore I need to do it from the scratch.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks you, the way you propose it's not exactly what I looked for. I was interested in making mathematica do what simulink does, just treat everything as it was numerical